# How to setup a view with a half of screen height?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I want to set view1's height to half of the screen's height for all devices (when the device in the portrait mode)

Here is what I want it to look like:

[image]

so I make an auto layout of View1's height

```
    @IBOutlet weak var heighConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

my viewwillappear function here:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self. heighConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height / 2
}
```

But it's not worked when I ran my app. what's wrong in here?

Comment: What it is showing? Is it going inside loop?

Comment: it's showing the view1's height which I setup on main storyboard

Comment: I've just edit my question for clearly understand.

Comment: How is your constraint attached to the storyboard? Can you show a screen-shot of the constraint in IB?

Comment: did you try didAppear or didLayed?

Comment: Why u don't set multiplier of 1:2 in the interface builder (much more cleaner).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to change `heightConstraint`'s constant value in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    heightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height / 2
}
```

Answer (score 31):

I know the accepted answer is correct but there is simpler method to do so -

Add the view (the one shown in yellow color). Pin it to three edges (top, leading and trailing). I have set it as 0 but change it as per your need.

[image]

Create Height Equal to constraint to main View as

[image]

[image]

Open that Constraint in the Inspector view and edit the multiplier as 0.5.
Setting it as 0.5 takes the height value of half the height of mainView.

[image]

Just make sure FirstItem = View1 and SecondItem = SuperView as shown in the image.

Comment: Hey. This is another way to "Rome" and I will take note this method. Thanks

Comment: Mention not. Alternatives in Xcode are inexhaustible !

Comment: Much better and easier in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out. Hope it will help you out. The below line will take the bounds of the device and will set the frame or height according to it.

```
view1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2);
```

Hope this helps!!! Good Luck...

Comment: Setting the frame doesn't work reliably when using auto-layout. You have to change constraints, as the OP is doing.